# Why are my pages indented differently

Tags: formatting, pdftex, indentation

I have written a test document to illustrate the strange behaviour I have encountered. When I compile the code, it indents the paragraph on the first page differently from the second paragraph but when I skip to the third page, the indentation matches the first page. Please help. My code is below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
%\nocite{*} % use if we want to see a list of all references 
%\input{title_page}
% \input{abstract}
% \input{table_of_contents}
% \input{introduction}
\section{dude}

\par sdfdsflsgssdfsd \newpage
\par sfsdfsfsfsdfsfsd \newpage
\par sfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfs \newpage

%\input{background}
% \input{research_questions}
% \input{approach}
% \input{related_work}
% \input{thesis_outline}
% \input{project_requirements}
% \input{timeline}
%\input{references}

\end{document} 
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xc8yvkqz6rlmayv/master.pdf?dl=0) to the document that gets produced:

Comment: You are using twoside. Probably that is your problem (keyword odd/evenside margin and BCOR with KOMA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the use of the `twoside` class option. It is no problem of indentation, but of margins. So the problem disappears by removing this class option. If you want a two-sided document then this is normal.